# How to define a range that includes both merged and non-merged cells?

Tags: excel, vba

Let's say I have cells A1 through E1. A1 and B1 are normal cells, while C1, D1, and E1 are all merged as one cell.

If I want to define a range as these three cells (meaning, from A1 through E1), this code isn't working for me:

```
Dim startRow, endRow, startColumn, endColumn As Long

startRow = 1
endRow = 1
startColumn = 1
endColumn = 3

Set rng = Range(Cells(startRow, startColumn), Cells(endRow, endColumn))
```

I have run this with the variable `endColumn` set to both 3 and 5 (the first and last column used in the merged cell) and neither of them work. My code returns an error each time, and I can only assume it is due to the merged cell in this range definition.

It seems like there should be a simple solution to this, but google isn't returning anything too helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @BigBen *sigh*, Massive brain fart. I've edited/corrected the original post. Should be A1 through E1, not A1 through A5. Thanks for pointing out the error!

Comment: What is the error? I could not reproduce it; it is running well. 
I added that to the end of the code to test: MsgBox "You have selected the range: " & Rng.Address

Comment: What is the error message? What line throws the error?

Comment: Side note: `startRow, endRow, startColumn` are *variants* if you don't declare each variable as `Long` expressly @tectactoe